# How to write following queries in MongoDB using aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Retrieve films with an actor living in "Spain",

Retrieve films with actor details.

Collections are:

```
db.actor.insert([{    "actorId" : "5",    "firstName" : "Ritik",    "lastName" : "Roshan",    "address" : {        "street" : "GM Road",        "city" : "Guwahati",        "state" : "Aasam",    "country" : "India",        "pincode" : "145145"    },    "contactDetails" : {        "email" : "Ritik.roshan@gmail.com",        "phoneno" : "9874584"     },    "age" : "52" }])
```

```
db.film.insert([{    "filmId" : "10","title" : "Doshti Ka Karishma",    "releaseOfYear" : "2001",    "category" : ["advanture","Romantic"],   
 "actor" : [{ "firstName" : "Ritik",    "lastName" : "Roshan"  },{ "firstName" : "Karishma",    "lastName" : "Kapoor"  }],
    "director" : [{ "firstName" : "Satish",        "lastName" : "Ambike" }],
    "releaseDetails" : { "place" : "Rajasthan", "date" : ISODate("2001-05-18T15:14:08.023Z"),    "rating" : "C"}}])
```

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$lookup` to join two collection

```
db.film.aggregate([
  { $match: { "releaseDetails.place": "Rajasthan" } },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "actor",
      "let": {
        actor: "$actor"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $in: [ "$firstName", "$$actor.firstName" ] },
                { $in: [ "$lastName", "$$actor.lastName" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "joinActors"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oJSW_cwwFOv)**

Note : You are saving `firstname` and `lastname` as reference in film collection. But combination of `firstname` and `lastname` are not always unique, Better you save `_id` of `actor` into the film collection's actor section.
something like this [Save ref id](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_cjvhOEypyi)